# How can I tell if the wireless network card in my laptop supports 802.11n?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n

I have a Dell laptop computer issued to me by my employer with an Internal network card. I am considering upgrading my home wifi network from 802.11g to 802.11n, but want to make sure the laptop will benefit from the upgrade.

Is there an easy way to tell if this internal modem supports the 802.11n standard, or maybe is there a way in the OS (Windows 7) to get the make/model of the card so I can look this information up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on Start orb, and right click on Computer -> Device Manager. Search for Network adapters, and right click on your wireless adapter. Most probably, the name should indicate if Wireless n is supported, else right click on the adapter -> properties -> Wireless mode. If there is 'n' mode here, then Wireless n is supported.

[image]

Comment: I got mixed results. The wireless mode did not have an entry for 802.11n. HOWEVER, there was a separate property for 802.11n mode, which is set to enabled. Not sure how to interpret this. I did look up the netcard name (Intel Wifi Link AGN) and it supposedly supports N.

Comment: Well in this case your wireless does support Wifi n

Comment: @JohnFx Are these what you see? : http://screenshoot.me/RduVYu, http://screenshoot.me/GqF0Nl, http://screenshoot.me/y62Mer, http://screenshoot.me/Notn0h

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy). It should tell you quite a lot about your network card under the Network section.

Even if your card doesn't support N, upgrading your router will still increase your bandwidth and range. That benefit is increased when both ends are N.

Comment: If my card doesn't support N then both ends wouldn't be N. I don't get your point.

Comment: Okay, compare this to sound, say a airhorn. If somebody blew an airhorn at you from some distance, you can hear the horn at some certain loudness. If the guy buys a louder airhorn, and you stand at the same distance, the airhorn is still louder to you, regardless of whether or not your ears have improved. Not only that, but you can hear the airhorn from a greater distance than before.

Comment: @digitxp Hmm, not really sure we'd understand that analogy..